# whhy am I getting ERROR: Failed to create process?

Tags: python

I am trying to automate the process using dynamorio 32 bits, and 64 bits, but however when I try to generate the trace command to execute and push with the path to the current test cases.

```py
    def worker(self, app, seed_corpus):
        trace_command = [
            self.DYNAMORIO,
            "-t", "drcov",
            "-logdir", self.CODE_COVERAGE,
            "--"
        ]
        for element in app:
            trace_command.append(element)
        output = subprocess.check_output(trace_command)
        return True
​
def worker(self, app, seed_corpus):
    trace_command = [
        self.DYNAMORIO,
        "-t", "drcov",
        "-logdir", self.CODE_COVERAGE,
        "--"
    ]

    print trace_command
    print app
    print seed_corpus
```

​
​
trace_command 
​
`['C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\fuzz\\DynamoRIO\\bin32\\drrun', '-t', 'drcov', '-logdir', 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\fuzz\\CODE_COVERAGE', '--']`
​
app
​

```
running....
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

​

## seed_corpus

```
running....
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\big.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\crash.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\exception.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\normal.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\bigalloc.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\crash_gs.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\hang.txt
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\small.txt
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

​
​
I am expecting `['C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\fuzz\\DynamoRIO\\bin32\\drrun', '-t', 'drcov', '-logdir', 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\fuzz\\CODE_COVERAGE', '--'] C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ConsoleApplication1.exe C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\CORPUS\big.txt` , but I am getting the output of `ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\fuzz\C":`

stackstrace

````
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 389, in _handle_results
    task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class 'subprocess.CalledProcessError'>, ())

ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":
ERROR: Failed to create process for "C:\Users\xxxx\C":```
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: update it......